# Could I know which jobs are not in any view of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins' view function to group my jobs. But I'm not sure do I lost any job.
Is it possible to find the job which not belongs to any view?
Or is it possible to find any job belongs to 2 views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this mess, I use regular expressions to assign jobs to view and a naming convention for the jobs. Everything else would be hit and miss.

In addition, a job will not show up in a view if you don't have permission for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I used this groovy script to list jobs without any associated view

```java
        Set<String> projects = new HashSet<>();
        final List<TopLevelItem> items = Jenkins.get().getItems();
        for (Item item : items) {
            projects.add(item.getFullName());
        }

        Set<String> projectsWithView = new HashSet<>();
        final Collection<View> views = Jenkins.get().getViews();
        for (View view : views) {
            if (!(view instanceof AllView)){
                final Collection<TopLevelItem> allItems = view.getAllItems();
                for (TopLevelItem allItem : allItems) {
                    projectsWithView.add(allItem.getFullName());
                }
            }
        }

        println(projects.size());
        projects.removeAll(projectsWithView);
        println(projects.size());
        println(projects);
```